# How to find the first 5 values of a recursive relation where certain sequences are not known?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Write down the first five values of each of the following recursive sequences.

(a) ***r***(0) = 2, ***r***(n) = [***r***(n-1)] -n -1 for all integers n>=1 (I couldn't write the values as ace of ***r*** and ***s*** so I just wrote them in brackets; any edit would be appreciated)

(b) ***s***(0) = 2, ***s***(n) = [***s***(n-1)] + [***s***(n-2)] +......+ [***s***(0)]^2

Part a is pretty simplee and I got values ***r***(1) = 2, ***r***(2) = 1, ***r***(3) = -3, ***r***(4) = 4, ***r***(5) = 10

I hope that is correct.

Part b am not really sure how I will do this. For n =1 I get ***s***(1) = ***s***(0)^2 +(-1)^2 +.....+***s***(0)^2

I have the value for ***s***(0) = 2 but how do I get the value for ***s***(-1) and the values in between ***s***(n-2)^2 and ***s***(0)^2?

Comment: Assuming that each term is suppose to be squared, you have $s_n=s_0^2+s_1^2+\dots+s_{n-1}^2$, so $s_1=s_0^2=4, s_2=s_0^2+s_1^2=20$ etc

Comment: How did you get s1 = 4? How did you get the value for s(-1)?

Comment: There is no value $s_{-1}$. The dots mean that you start at $s_0$ and only go up as far as $s_{n-1}$. So for $n=1$ there is only one term on the right hand side and we have $s_1=s_0^2$.

Comment: Your values for $r_n$ are not quite right. You should have $r_0=2,r_1=0,r_2=-3,r_3=-7,r_4=-12$. For (b) you should have $s_0=2,s_1=4,s_2=20,s_3=420,s_4=176820$.